# How to update text of a Scrollbar in Tkinter?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, graphics, tkinter-text

I am trying to create a scrollable text view with Tkinter. I tried something like this:

```
root = Tk()
scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

textbox = Text(root)
textbox.pack()

textbox.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.config(command=textbox.yview)

for line in lines:
    textbox.insert(END, line)

root.mainloop()
```

But other than the insert() function, I haven't found a way to change the text widget.
How can I update the entire scrollbar's text after already inserting lines into it?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you are asking, but you can delete all the text using `textbox.delete("1,0", END)` and then use `textbox.insert` to add items again.

Comment: Your code works as expected. The scrollbar will automatically update as you add and delete text from the widget. It's unclear what you mean by "update the entire scrollbar's text" since a scrollbar doesn't have a text attribute.